# compling python 3.5 program with pyinstall - missing tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a python 3.5 program, which uses tkinter as a GUI. To do that I am using pyinstall, but I run into a problem during compliation process I get warning messages" tkinter not found" and the program does not work afterwards (as a dist version). It seems pyinstaller is looking for tkinter.py but from what I undersant python 3.x uses __init__py. How should I proceed compiling this program? I have ran through the documentation on pyinstaller page, but it wasn't helpful, or I missed something...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbHfl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the hidden import feature when compiling. Add the following as an option when compiling your script:
--hidden-import tkinter